# Rstudio knit error

Tags: rstudio

I'm trying to knit a Rmd file in Rstudio and I keep getting error saying that it cannot find a function in package mice even though the package is installed and loaded. I have no problem running the code as is, only knitting it. It also does not matter what I knit it into - pdf, html, or word - I get the same error. When I commented out the line with that function it gave me the same error for another function in that package. I update everything but I still get the same error.
This is the error:
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "complete"
Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
getAnywhere("complete")
```

where is the package providing that function located? Is that package loaded in your `.Rmd` file?

Comment: It says:    package:mice
  namespace:mice
  namespace:Rcpp     but it's actually working now anyway. I think updating everything helped. Thanks for you help!